# How to install eclipse photon in 16.04?

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to install eclipse java ide in ubuntu 16.04. I am really struggling to do this. I want to install it to my /opt directory, and make it launchible from the ubuntu dash.

[here](https://www.hastebin.com/riruyaveko.swift) is the error i get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing the Eclipse Java Photon directly instead of installing from the installer. You can download package of Eclipse photon you want from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/).

To launch it from Dash consider making a [Desktop Entry](https://askubuntu.com/a/64237/816190).